# rspec - adding a helper module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, delayed-job

I'm following this example here: http://erikonrails.snowedin.net/?p=230

I added:

```
lib/delayed_job_spec_helper.rb
```

Then in my rspec I have:

```
describe Thingy do
  include DelayedJobSpecHelper

  it "should have been worked on if I do something that queues jobs" do
    thing = Thingy.new
    thing.method_that_queues_jobs
    work_off
    thing.should be_worked_on
  end
end
```

Problem is I get the error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant DelayedJobSpecHelper (NameError)
```

Ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this discussion, it might be connected to your problem.

http://www.mail-archive.com/thinking-sphinx@googlegroups.com/msg05036.html